# Xamarin Forms Shell FlyoutItem

Tags: shell, xamarin.forms, flyout

I would like to make my app have three flyout menu options as follows:

**Configuration**

**Collect Data**

**About**

When a user selects the Configuration flyout menu option, I would like there to be a bottom group of two tabs that say

**Network Configuration** ------ **Data Configuration**

I only want the bottom tabs visible when the Configuration flyout menu option is selected.  Is there a way to do this in Xaml or do I need to do it in code manually showing and hiding the bottom tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it in Xaml. You can define differnet `ShellContent` in each `FlyoutItem`.

Create a new project with `Shell template` and then add those codes to config shell:

```
 <Shell.FlyoutHeader>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="Black">
            <Label Text="Test"
               TextColor="White"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </Shell.FlyoutHeader>

    <FlyoutItem Title="Configuration"
                >
        <ShellContent Title="Network Configuration">
            <views:NetworkConfiguration />
            </ShellContent>

        <ShellContent Title="Data Configuration">
            <views:DataConfiguration />
        </ShellContent>


    </FlyoutItem>

    <FlyoutItem Title="Collect Data"
                >
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent Title="Configuration"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:Page2}" />
            <ShellContent Title="Collect Data"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:Page3}" />
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>


    <FlyoutItem Title="About">

        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:AboutPage}" />

    </FlyoutItem>
```

You can refer this example: [shell-example-xamarin.forms](https://github.com/XfHua/shell-example-xamarin.forms)